# Docker Nginx Returns 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a docker image simulating my **LocalHost**
I configured the Nginx PHP and Mariadb but when i open the sepecified port of Nginx, returns **502 Bad Gateway**
then i said ok maybe PHPMyadmin might open but event that didnt opened.
Idk whats the problem, I followed up many solutions but the results were same.

My `docker-compose.yml` File:

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
    nginx_php82_mariadb_phpmyadmin:

services:
    nginx_service:
        container_name: nginx_container
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        ports:
            - "8010:8010"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/App
            - ./.docker/Nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        depends_on:
            - php82_service
            - mariadb_service
        networks:
            - nginx_php82_mariadb_phpmyadmin

    php82_service:
        container_name: php82_container
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./.docker/PHP/Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "9010:9010"
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/App
        networks:
            - nginx_php82_mariadb_phpmyadmin

    mariadb_service:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: mariadb_container
        ports:
            - "4410:4410"
        volumes:
            - ./.docker/Mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: toor
        networks:
            - nginx_php82_mariadb_phpmyadmin

    phpmyadmin_service:
        container_name: phpmyadmin_container
        image: phpmyadmin:latest
        ports:
            - "7010:7010"
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        depends_on:
            - nginx_service
            - mariadb_service
        networks:
            - nginx_php82_mariadb_phpmyadmin
```

And my Nginx **default.conf**:

```
server {
    listen 8010;
    index index.php;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/App/public;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;

    location / {
       try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php82_service:9010;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;

        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

**I am trying to access the project with both
127.0.0.1:8010 & localhost:8010**

[image: Docker Container Image]

Comment: please share the screen shot of docker container ls

Comment: Also the url which you are trying to access

Comment: @Shibon i just Shared!!

Comment: just try by changing port 
ports:
            - "8010:80"



in ngnix config 
    listen 80;

Comment: docker container ls this details too

Comment: @Shibon I did try "8010:80" and still have the same error I have Apache on my laptop and port 80 is occupied. And what is docker container ls? don't you mean containers list?